DSC v3 for Linux And Integration with Azure
hope this post finds you well!
I'm trying to figure out how to implement DSC for Ubuntu and RedHat machines on Azure. From the looks into the documentation of DSC v3. From the looks of it, DSC v3 is only intended to be used with Azure Policy Guest Configuration - Can someone confirm this?
If I want to run a bash script to ensure falcon-sensor is running with the proper unique agent ID, how would one go about that? I already have a script, but I'm unsure how to get that script running as a part of DSC through Azure.
Any guidance would immensely be appreciated
What I've been able to do so far:
I've been able to create a configuration file with nxtools to ensure falcon-sensor is running. However bcz I have a bunch of things I need to test, I want to run a bash script.
Configuration falconSensor {

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'nxtools'

    node localhost {

        nxService ensureFalconSensorRunning {

            Name    = 'falcon-sensor.service'

            State   = 'running'

            Enabled = $true

        }

    }

}

falconSensor

Script to convert the Configuration File to Azure Policy
.\DSC_Script.ps1

# Create a package that will only audit compliance
$params = @{
    Name          = 'falconSensorv2'
    Configuration = './falconSensor/localhost.mof'
    Type          = 'Audit'
    Force         = $true
}
New-GuestConfigurationPackage @params

#Link to Azure Storage Blob where I put the Configuration Package (.zip) file
$uri = '{storage_BLOBURI}’

# generate new GUID
$guid = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString() 
# create policy definition and save locally
$PolicyConfig = @{
PolicyId = $guid
ContentUri = $uri
DisplayName = 'TestPolicyCustom'
Description = '<YourDescription>'
Path = './'
Platform = 'Linux'
Mode = 'Audit' # Audit, ApplyAndMonitor, or ApplyAndAutoCorrect
PolicyVersion = '1.0.0'
}

Write-Output 'Creating policy definition'
New-GuestConfigurationPolicy @PolicyConfig -Verbose

# Publish policy definition to Azure
$JsonPath = './falconSensorv2_AuditIfNotExists.json'
$PolicyJson = Get-Content -Path $JsonPath -Raw
Write-Output 'Publishing policy definition to Azure'
New-AzPolicyDefinition -Name ‘{name}’ -Policy $PolicyJson -Verbose


Did you get a chance to look into this blog  and MSDoc
